# Maven Exclude tag

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I am trying to exclude a file during packaging in maven.
I do not no the file path. It can be present in any directory.

```
<exclude>filename.xml</exclude>
```

is the way I am trying currently. I wonder if this would work across all the paths or just current directory. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that it's a resource file, you can use something like the below to exclude all files with that name

```
<resources>
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <excludes>
      <exclude>**/filename.xml</exclude>
    </excludes>
  </resource>
</resources>
```

Comment: Sweet! Thanks. So by doing it my way, would it look only in the current directory?? (Just trying to learn)

Comment: yes right, you might get some information from http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html